# "Associativity" of group extensions

Tags: group-theory

Consider the following situation. I have given a group extension (we will say that $G$ is $N$ by $Q$)
$$
1 \to N \to G \xrightarrow{p} Q \to 1.
$$
Now suppose also $Q$ can be written as a group extension as follows:
$$
1 \to A \to Q \xrightarrow{q} B \to 1.
$$
We can now rearrange the two group extensions as follows:
$$
1 \to \ker(q \circ p ) \to G \to B \to 1
$$
$$
1 \to N \to \ker(q \circ p ) \to A \to 1
$$
More succinctly one could say that "$N$ by $Q$ = $N$ by ($A$ by $B$) = ($N$ by $A$) by $B$".

Now I am intersted in the similar situation where $N$ is given as a group extension instead of $Q$:
$$
1 \to A \to N \to B \to 1
$$
I would like to have a similar result saying that "($A$ by $B$) by $Q$ = $A$ by ($B$ by $Q$)". However one has the problem that $A \unlhd N \unlhd G$, but normality is not transitive. So in general it does not follow that $A \unlhd G$. If this was the case (for example, if $A$ was a characteristic subgroup of $N$), than indeed one could get the result I hoped for.

Am I missing something? Where can I find an account on such formal properties of iterated group extensions?

Comment: Isn't this backwards from the standard usage of "by"?

Comment: One usually says that $G$ is an extension of $Q$ by $N$. However for group properties $\mathcal P$ and $\mathcal Q$ one says that $G$ is $\mathcal P$ by $\mathcal Q$ if $N$ has $\mathcal P$ and $Q$ has $\mathcal Q$. I was adopting the latter convention.